# $_POST not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

my login form is:

http://www.khabgahfeiz.ir/admin/login

in my controller:

```
    public function handling() {

        var_dump($_POST['email']);
        return;
....
```

but it return `null` value and I got this error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: email

Filename: backend/login.php

Line Number: 29
```

Comment: just do var_dump($_POST) and see what is returning

Comment: please check your autoload.php file $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form','security','date','cookie','download');

Comment: @ Divyesh Savaliya it returns `array(0) { } `.

Comment: Try this $this->input->post() with print_r();

Comment: Make sure your filename has first letter uppercase Login.php same as class

Comment: @Mayank Pandey it returns `bool(false) `;

Comment: It may be because of the my `.htaccess`?

Comment: make sure , URL and FORM helpers are loaded.

Comment: `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form','security','date','cookie','download');`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->input->post()`.
For e.g.:

```
$this->input->post('table field'=>'form element name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in your controller

```
echo $this->input->post('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Input All Post**  $data=$this->input->post();
**And For Single post* $name=$this->input->post('name');

Answer (score 0):

I changed it :

```
 $config['base_url']    = 'http://khabgahfeiz.ir/';
```

to :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.khabgahfeiz.ir/';
```